# How to call/access a singleton method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Here is the code that I want to call in Swift:

```
+ (Client*) clientWithInfo:(ServerInfo*)info {
    return [[[Client alloc] initWithInfo:info] autorelease];
}
```

Here is how I am calling it in Swift:

```
Client.clientWithInfo(ServerInfo)
```

But it gives me the following error:

> clientWithInfo unavailable: use object construction Client(info:)

Comment: Seems like duplicate of : [How to call an Objective-C singleton from Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24148464/how-to-call-an-objective-c-singleton-from-swift)

Comment: Use Client(info:ServerInfo)

Comment: that's not a singleton

Answer (score 0):

First you need to have bridging headers and in this file included name of your class.

```
#import "MySingletonClass.h"
```

After you should be able to call MySingleton.sharedInstance.methodName

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply, but i already imported required headers into my bridging header file.

Answer (score 0):

Start by reading Apple's guide [Using Swift with Objective-C (Swift 2.1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html). There's a section on importing Objective-C into Swift.

You need to create a  Objective-C bridging header file. When you add a Swift file to an Objective-C project or an Objective-C file to a Swift project Xcode will ask you if you want to add an Objective-C bridging header?

[image]

To use your Objective-C code with your Swift code you would import every Objective-C header you want to expose to swift. Note that this is for the same target.

```
#import "MyCustomObjectiveCCodeWithSingleton.h"
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html):

> Any public Objective-C headers listed in this bridging header file
>   will be visible to Swift. The Objective-C functionality will be
>   available in any Swift file within that target automatically, without
>   any import statements. Use your custom Objective-C code with the same
>   Swift syntax you use with system classes.