# Unable to call specific Objective-C class method in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am using `AFNetworking 2.3.1`:

```
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx")!)
var requestOperation = AFHTTPRequestOperation(request: request)
requestOperation.responseSerializer = AFImageResponseSerializer()
```

I have an error at third line using Swift 1.1 (Xcode 6.1 beta 2 build 6A1030):

```
'init()' is unavailable: superseded by import of -[NSObject init]
```

This line should looks like this on Objective-C:

```
requestOperation.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];
```

I think this problem is related to Swift auto-bridging from Objective-C. Any ideas to solve this?

[image]

**UPDATE:**

This way doesn't works:

```
AFImageResponseSerializer.serializer()
```

And error description is very nice:

```
'serializer()' is unavailable: use object construction 'AFHTTPResponseSerializer()'
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Right now I found a temporarily solution. I added this code to bridging header:

```
@interface AFImageResponseSerializer (CustomInit)
+ (instancetype)sharedSerializer;
@end
```

and code added to "bridging-header" implementation file:

```
@implementation AFImageResponseSerializer (CustomInit)
+ (instancetype)sharedSerializer {
    return [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];
}
@end
```

And used it like this:

```
AFImageResponseSerializer.sharedSerializer()
```

Comment: Works for me! Thanks. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24093693/create-swift-instance-from-objective-c-factory-method

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It was caused by becoming stricter of conversion to the base class in XCode 6.1.
So, you need upcasting, like below.

```
requestOperation.responseSerializer = AFImageResponseSerializer() as AFHTTPResponseSerializer
```

Comment: Thank you! How did you discovered this solution? :)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a class method, you probably want `AFImageResponseSerializer.serializer()`

Comment: Just added UPDATE to question